# How to obtain process id using Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

Hi I want to get process id of process which I started.
I tried to use "Process" library and Start Process / Get Process Id but I get error that:
'data' is not supported by this keyword.

```
Get pid
  [Arguments]   ${session}   ${token}   ${domain}   ${task_name}   ${params}=${EMPTY}
  &{headers} =   Create Dictionary   Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  ...   domain=${domain}   Accept=application/json   Authorization=${token}
  ${current_date} =  Get Current Date   result_format=%Y%m%d
  ${data} =   Create Dictionary   id=${task_name}   hold=false   processingTimestamp=${current_date}   parameters=${params}
  Start Process   POST Request   ${session}   /api/processing/executeNow   data=${data}   headers=${headers}   alias=check_id
  ${pid} =   Get Process Id   check_id
  [Return]   ${pid}
```

The error appear because "POST Request" has its own arguments.
Could someone help me with this and tell how should I change it or maybe have different idea?

Thank you very much for all comments

Answer (score 3):

`Start Process` is to start a command that you could start from the command line/shell/terminal. `POST`is not a command.

You could try to convert the command to `curl` (if you have it installed) and use it with `Start Process`.